# Iptables TCP NEW state vs TCP flags in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, iptables

I would like to double check what is the behaviour of NEW state in TCP connections in iptables (Ubuntu 22.04).

Does it only accept SYN=1 and ACK=0/FIN=0/RST=0 in tcp flags?

More detailed example - let's say I have below rule on my server:

```
iptables -A INPUT   -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

Client sends packet with SYN=1 AND eg. FIN=1 or RST=1. Will such packet be matched by above ACCEPT rule?

I was reading a bit old iptables docs and below part made me thinking if this is still something to be worried about with recent kernel/implementations in Ubuntu:
https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/iptables-tutorial.html#NEWNOTSYN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP packets with SYN=1 AND eg. FIN=1 or RST=1 will NOT be matched by your rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT   -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

Experimental test:
I wrote this example iptables rule set, where packets are only logged and not accepted or dropped.

```
doug@s19:~/iptables/misc$ cat tcp-new-and-flags
#!/bin/sh
FWVER=0.02
#
# tcp-new-and-flags Smythies 2023.10.05 Ver:0.02
#       Change the script name, so it'll be easier to find in future.
#
# ask1488093 Smythies 2023.10.05 Ver:0.01
#       See here:
#       https://askubuntu.com/questions/1488093/iptables-tcp-new-state-vs-tcp-flags-in-ubuntu-22-04
#       run as sudo
#

echo "Loading tcp-new-and-flags rule set version $FWVER..\n"

# The location of the iptables program
#
IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables

#Setting the EXTERNAL and INTERNAL interfaces and addresses for the network
#
# Smythies (for testing)
EXTIF="br0"
EXTIP="192.168.111.136"
NETWORK="192.168.111.0/24"
UNIVERSE="0.0.0.0/0"

#Clearing any previous configuration
#
echo "  Clearing any existing rules and setting default policies.."
$IPTABLES -P INPUT ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -F INPUT
$IPTABLES -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -F OUTPUT
$IPTABLES -P FORWARD ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -F FORWARD
# Delete user defined chains
$IPTABLES -X
# Reset all IPTABLES counters
$IPTABLES -Z

# loopback interfaces are valid.
#
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i lo -s $UNIVERSE -d $UNIVERSE -j ACCEPT

# Allow any related traffic coming back to the server in.
#
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -s $UNIVERSE -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# A NEW TCP connection requires SYN bit set and FIN,RST,ACK reset.
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "NEW TCP no SYN:" --log-level info

# Just DROP invalid packets.
#
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -p tcp -m state --state INVALID -j LOG --log-prefix "INVALID:" --log-level info

# The main rules.
#
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "NEW C TCP:" --log-level info
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -p tcp -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "NEW S TCP:" --log-level info

echo tcp-new-and-flags set version $FWVER done.
```

Then I used `hping3` to send TCP packets with the desired test flags from another computer:

Test 1: SYN=1 and FIN=1:

```
doug@s15:~$ sudo /usr/sbin/hping3 -p 25565 --count 1 --syn --fin s19
HPING s19 (br0 192.168.111.136): SF set, 40 headers + 0 data bytes
len=46 ip=192.168.111.136 ttl=64 DF id=0 sport=25565 flags=RA seq=0 win=0 rtt=3.8 ms

--- s19 hping statistic ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 3.8/3.8/3.8 ms
```

And via tcpdump I got:

```
2023-10-05 12:09:43.079575 IP 192.168.111.1.1642 > 192.168.111.136.25565: Flags [FS], seq 1968173429, win 512, length 0
2023-10-05 12:09:43.079689 IP 192.168.111.136.25565 > 192.168.111.1.1642: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 1968173431, win 0, length 0
```

And the iptables:

```
doug@s19:~/iptables/misc$ sudo iptables -xvnL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 21 packets, 1300 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
      13      692 ACCEPT     all  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
       0        0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 state NEW LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "NEW TCP no SYN:"
       1       40 LOG        tcp  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state INVALID LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "INVALID:"
       0        0 LOG        tcp  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "NEW C TCP:"
       0        0 LOG        tcp  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "NEW S TCP:"

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 12 packets, 1268 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Observe, via the packet counters, the packet state was classified as INVALID.

Test 2: SYN=1 and RST=1:

```
doug@s15:~$ sudo /usr/sbin/hping3 -p 25565 --count 1 --syn --rst s19
HPING s19 (br0 192.168.111.136): RS set, 40 headers + 0 data bytes

--- s19 hping statistic ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.0/0.0/0.0 ms
```

And via tcpdump I got:

```
2023-10-05 12:14:17.915848 IP 192.168.111.1.2976 > 192.168.111.136.25565: Flags [SR], seq 1102554713, win 512, length 0
```

And the iptables:

```
doug@s19:~/iptables/misc$ sudo iptables -xvnL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 72 packets, 4635 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       2      100 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
      38     1994 ACCEPT     all  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
       0        0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 state NEW LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "NEW TCP no SYN:"
       2       80 LOG        tcp  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state INVALID LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "INVALID:"
       0        0 LOG        tcp  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "NEW C TCP:"
       0        0 LOG        tcp  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "NEW S TCP:"

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 38 packets, 4800 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Observe there has been another INVALID packet.

Test 2: SYN=0 and ACK=1:

```
doug@s15:~$ sudo /usr/sbin/hping3 -p 25565 --count 1 --ack s19
HPING s19 (br0 192.168.111.136): A set, 40 headers + 0 data bytes
len=46 ip=192.168.111.136 ttl=64 DF id=0 sport=25565 flags=R seq=0 win=0 rtt=7.8 ms

--- s19 hping statistic ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 7.8/7.8/7.8 ms
```

And via tcpdump I got:

```
2023-10-05 12:18:31.196161 IP 192.168.111.1.2342 > 192.168.111.136.25565: Flags [.], ack 1541434780, win 512, length 0
2023-10-05 12:18:31.196319 IP 192.168.111.136.25565 > 192.168.111.1.2342: Flags [R], seq 1541434780, win 0, length 0
```

And the iptables:

```
doug@s19:~/iptables/misc$ sudo iptables -xvnL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 109 packets, 7304 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       2      100 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
      56     2837 ACCEPT     all  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
       1       40 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 state NEW LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "NEW TCP no SYN:"
       2       80 LOG        tcp  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state INVALID LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "INVALID:"
       1       40 LOG        tcp  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "NEW C TCP:"
       1       40 LOG        tcp  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "NEW S TCP:"

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 60 packets, 8604 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Observe the packet was classified as NEW, but was also caught by the `NEW TCP no SYN` rule, where it would normally be dropped.

The `/var/log/syslog` entries:

```
Oct  5 12:09:28 s19 kernel: [261594.730257] INVALID:IN=br0 OUT= MAC=deleted SRC=192.168.111.1 DST=192.168.111.136 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=45686 PROTO=TCP SPT=2608 DPT=25565 WINDOW=512 RES=0x00 SYN FIN URGP=0
Oct  5 12:09:43 s19 kernel: [261608.954625] INVALID:IN=br0 OUT= MAC=deleted SRC=192.168.111.1 DST=192.168.111.136 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=61927 PROTO=TCP SPT=1642 DPT=25565 WINDOW=512 RES=0x00 SYN FIN URGP=0
Oct  5 12:14:17 s19 kernel: [261883.796409] INVALID:IN=br0 OUT= MAC=deleted SRC=192.168.111.1 DST=192.168.111.136 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=56125 PROTO=TCP SPT=2976 DPT=25565 WINDOW=512 RES=0x00 RST SYN URGP=0
Oct  5 12:18:31 s19 kernel: [262137.081851] NEW TCP no SYN:IN=br0 OUT= MAC=deleted SRC=192.168.111.1 DST=192.168.111.136 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=10150 PROTO=TCP SPT=2342 DPT=25565 WINDOW=512 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
Oct  5 12:18:31 s19 kernel: [262137.081889] NEW C TCP:IN=br0 OUT= MAC=deleted SRC=192.168.111.1 DST=192.168.111.136 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=10150 PROTO=TCP SPT=2342 DPT=25565 WINDOW=512 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
Oct  5 12:18:31 s19 kernel: [262137.081915] NEW S TCP:IN=br0 OUT= MAC=deleted SRC=192.168.111.1 DST=192.168.111.136 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=10150 PROTO=TCP SPT=2342 DPT=25565 WINDOW=512 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
```

See [also](https://www.linuxtopia.org/Linux_Firewall_iptables/x6193.html).

Comment: Absolutely brilliant answer! THANKS :D